# PHP validation error

Tags: php, html, validation, error-handling

Here I want to validate my drop down box so that if select... is selected then it will error. I have done this but when the form is submitted the error is not caught and it just submits. ##JUST TO CLARIFY I HAVE ALLREADY TIRED TO PUT 0 AND IT STILL DID NOT WORK.##

Here is my HTML

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Submit Form</title> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>All fields marked with an asterisk "<span style="color: red">*</span>"are mandatory.</p>
    &nbsp;
    <form name="SubmitForm" method="post" action="SubmitForm.php">
        <table>
        <tr>
             <td valign="top" width=250px>
             <label for="first_name"><span style="font-weight:bold">First Name <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
             </td>
                  <td valign="top">
             <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
             </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td valign="top"">
                 <label for="last_name"><span style="font-weight:bold">Last Name <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
             </td>
     <td valign="top">
     <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
     </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <td valign="top">
         <label for="email"><span style="font-weight:bold">Email Address <span style="color:    red">*</span></label>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
         <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td valign="top">
         <label for="telephone"><span style="font-weight:bold">Telephone Number <span style="color: red">*</span></label>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
         <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td valign="top">
         <label for="formFood"><span style="font-weight:bold"> What is your favourite food?<span style="color: red">*</span>
         </td>
         <td valign="top">
         <select name="formFood" style="display:inline">
                 <option value="0">Select...</option>
                 <option value="L">Lasagne</option>
                 <option value="F">Fish and Chips</option>
                 <option value="T">Toad in the Hole</option>
                 <option value="S">Steak and Chips</option>
         </select>
        </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
         <td height="30">
         </td>
     </tr>

     <tr> 
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://localhost/var/www/pages    /SubmitForm.php"> </a>
         </td>
     </tr>

       </table>
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php
          if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    //Mail to this email
    $email_to = "submitform2@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Submit form";


    function died($error) {
        // Begin error code
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['formFood'])) {
         died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required
    $formFood = $_POST['formFood']; // required

    $error_message = "Please Enter correct values into all mandatory Feilds";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(isset($_REQUEST['formFood']) && $_REQUEST['formFood'] == '0') { 
  echo 'Please select a Food.'; 
} 

  if(strlen($telephone) > 11) {
    died($error_message); }
  if(strlen($telephone) < 11 ) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  mail("submitform2@gmail.com", $email_subject,
  $email_message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
  }

?>
 <script>
alert("Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.")
 </script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @ Luke Rixson: use empty instead of isset.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that I have already tried it with a zero and it still errors i changed that to the string just to see if it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be
 `if(isset($_REQUEST['formFood']) && $_REQUEST['formFood'] == 0) { 
  echo 'Please select a Food.'; 
}`

Comment: please see above as I have already done this and it still doesn't work. What you saw was a result of my trail and error.

Comment: Instead of echoing select food, add it to the error message variable. When you want to submit, check if error_message is empty. If it is submit, else don't submit

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking value of option, but option's text:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['formFood']) && $_REQUEST['formFood'] == 'Select...') { 
  echo 'Please select a Food.'; 
}
```

It has to be:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['formFood']) && $_REQUEST['formFood'] == '0') { 
  echo 'Please select a Food.'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `0`, use an empty value for the `<option>` that you don't want to be valid, i.e. `<option value="">Select...</option>`. Just a good practice in general... and if at some point you decide to include front-end validation, this configuration works well out of the box, too.

When you check for the $_POST variable, use this instead:

```
// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    (!isset($_POST['formFood'] || empty($_POST['formFood']))) {
     died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the submitted value for select is 'Food...' but the value you should check for is '0' (the number set in the value of the select box, not the title.

See below:

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST['formFood']) && $_REQUEST['formFood'] == '0') { 
 echo 'Please select a Food.';
```

Answer (score 0):

use if (empty ($_POST ['formFood'])) if value is = 0 it will return false

```
 Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

The following things are considered to be empty:

    "" (an empty string)
    0 (0 as an integer)
    0.0 (0 as a float)
    "0" (0 as a string)
    NULL
    FALSE
    array() (an empty array)
    $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```